# In C, how do I extract the different parts of a string that are all separated by the \0 null terminator?

Tags: c, string, null-terminated

So in the following code, I want to store each section in the corresponding variable. Is there an easier way to do this rather than looping through the entire string char by char and checking if it's equal to \0 or not?

```
int main()
{
    char *test = "Hello My\0friends\0I love food!";
    
    char *section1; // Hello My
    char *section2; // friends
    char *section3; // I love food!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If a string is containing `\0` in it anywhere but its end, then it is not a string in terms of C.

Comment: Assign the addresses of the first char of the subtext: `char *section1 = test; char *section2 = &test[9]; char *section3 = &test[17]`.

Comment: In this case iteration would work since you know how many strings there are. It would be more difficult if you did not: how would you know when to stop looking without some marker? Like maybe an extra `\0` at the end.

Comment: I fact one can use `strlen`

Comment: Question more correct as "how do I extract the different parts of a _string literal_ that are all separated by the \0 null terminator?".  A _string_ ends at the first `'\0'`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Or more generally - array of `char`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If we have an _array of char_ then that supposes the last `char` may differ from `'\0'`.  OP goal relies on the _array of char_ or _string literal_ having 3+ _null characters_ and likely wants it to end with the 3rd null character..  Unclear what OP would want with `char a[] = { 'a', 0, 'b', 0, 'c', 0, 'd' }`.

Comment: *Is there an easier way to do this rather than looping through the entire string char by char?* Is there a way that''s easier on you, or on the computer?  *Somebody* is going to have to step through that array, one character at a time, looking for embedded `\0` characters.  You can write code involving `const char *p` and `*p++` to do that yourself, or you can use standard library functions such as `strlen` or `strchr` or `strrchr` to do it for you, but somewhere, there's going to be a loop stepping through the array one character at a time.

Comment: See also [How does the function Strrchr find the last c if c == '\0'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69930229/how-does-the-function-strrchr-finds-the-last-c-if-c-0)

Comment: If you want to do this sort of thing, I recommend using `char *test = "Hello My\0friends\0I love food!\0";` so that you can look for two `\0`'s in a row to unambiguously indicate the end of your sequence of strings.

Answer (score 4):

You have a character array containing multiple strings.

```
section1 = test;
section2 = test + strlen(test) +1;
section3 = section2 + strlen(section2) + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
const char * test = "Hello My\0friends\0I love food!";
const char * section1 = test;
const char * section2 = strchr(section1, 0) + 1;
const char * section3 = strchr(section2, 0) + 1;
```

Also, note that the section variables are just pointers into the `test` string.  That's fine if you are defining `test` the way I did above, but if you are defining `test` in some other more complicated way, you need to make sure the `test` string does not get deallocated or modified, or you need to make copies of the section strings before that happens.

Don't forget to include `string.h` at the top of your program.

However, I'd like to add that if you didn't know about the `strchr` function, it should be trivial to implement it yourself by writing a loop that iterates through the string and looks for a null character and returns the pointer to it.

Comment: Does `strrchr` really work with `\0` ? Is it guaranteed to work? Looks like you can use `strlen` instead.

Comment: amazing, thnak you!

Comment: Using `strchr` (or `strlen`) seems more sensible than `strrchr`.  Although `strrchr` might work, it's much less obvious whether it does.

Comment: Oh yeah, `strchr` makes more sense, since it returns the first occurence instead of the last occurence.  Both functions should be fine, since the standard explicitly says they support finding a pointer to the null terminator character.

Comment: In C, string literals are not `const` qualified; the pointer that results from the automatic conversion of an array to a pointer has type `char *`, not `const char *`. (In C++, they are `const`.)

Comment: Indeed, it *is* guaranteed to work as per *"The strchr function locates the first occurrence of c (converted to a char) in the string pointed to by s. **The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string**."*

Comment: For those wondering, `strrchr` is guaranteed to work also.  We [covered this a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69930229).

Comment: A string literal is an "array of static storage duration" (6.4.5 para 6), so there's no need to make a copy. As Eric says, it's element type is `char`, not `const char`, but that's not an invitation; any attempt to modify the contents of a string literal is undefined behaviour (q.v.) so you should treat it as though it were immutable.